# FLTK Fl_Choice obtain selected item

Tags: visual-c++, fltk

I want to get the selected item of users but it gives an error on this code:

```
choice->value();
```

hopes you kind guys can help me.

```
    Fl_Choice*    choice;
    int    i   =   0;

    void but_cb(Fl_Button* obj, void*)
    {
        i = choice->value();
        cout<<i;
    }
    int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Fl_Double_Window* win = new Fl_Double_Window(400,400,"Sample");
    win->begin();
    Fl_Choice* choice = new Fl_Choice(100,100,100,100,"Name");
    choice->add("Peter");
    choice->add("Tom");
    choice->add("Mary");
    Fl_Button* but = new Fl_Button(300,300,50,50,"Selected");
    but->callback((Fl_Callback*)but_cb);
    win->show();
    return (Fl::run());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not spend much time reading the code, so the modified, and commented code below may not be solution to your problem. I believe `choice` is NULL in `but_cb()` as you are redefining choice in your main() function, hiding the global 'choice' pointer.

```
Fl_Choice* choice;
int i = 0;

void but_cb(Fl_Button* obj, void*) {
    i = choice->value(); // uses global `choice` pointer to Fl_Choice.
    cout << i;
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Fl_Double_Window* win = new Fl_Double_Window(400,400,"Sample");
    win->begin();
        /* You are redefining choice here! BAD, because but_cb uses the global one.
        Fl_Choice* choice = new Fl_Choice(100,100,100,100,"Name");
        */

        // Good, assigns to the global `choice`, so it won't be NULL when but_cb is called
        choice = new Fl_Choice(100,100,100,100,"Name"); 

        choice->add("Peter");
        choice->add("Tom");
        choice->add("Mary");
        Fl_Button* but = new Fl_Button(300,300,50,50,"Selected");
        but->callback((Fl_Callback*)but_cb);
    win->show();
    return (Fl::run());
}
```